# I am trying to use operator overloading in c++ but when I go to implement the function, it provides this error

Tags: c++, c++14

The prototype for my function is this:
const String operator+(const String&) const;

When I go to implement the function, I have this:
String String::operator+(const String&)
{

}

This is providing an error and the only way it shows to fix it in my IDE is to change the prototype which I cannot do bc that was given in my assignment.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the error ? and please show some code, Do you implement your own String ?.

Answer (score -1):

The return value of your prototype is const String whereas the return value in the implementation is String (i.e. without the const qualifier). In general you should provide more detail of your code